# iOS: GMSCameraPosition is viewingAngle returns zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am creating a google map view where I want to set viewingAngle of GMSCameraPosition 45 degree. I tried to set this in viewDidLoad but it returns zero as I print the same in log and angle is not set.

This is what I have in my viewDidLoad,

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                              longitude:151.2086
                                              zoom:19
                                              bearing:0
                                              viewingAngle:45]; 
NSLog(@"Angle:%f",mapView.camera.viewingAngle);
```

Above code returns me,

```
Angle:0.000000
```

in log, whats actual issue ? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"Angle:%f", camera.viewingAngle);`? What's mapview for?

Comment: Mate, its GMSMapView * mapView. Actually I dont want to just log it, I want to change camera angle.

Comment: But you never assign the value for it though. mapView.camera = camera?

Comment: I didnt. I havent assigned this value.

Comment: So what do you want it to do? magically update the Angle without even assigning the value over? I mean you are `NSLog`ing a value that is not yet initialized from you snippet.

Comment: Ok mate. I did'nt know that. Let me try once.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing **zero (0)** as the **bearing** when creating the camera. Instead, pass **45**.